# react-navigation-fluid-transitions shared image flickers

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, shared-element-transition

I'm learning how to make beautiful animations with react native, and I have problems using the react-native-fluid-transitions library.

When I use shared elements with images, they flicker during transitions and only appear at the end of transition, does anyone had the same problem ? I didn't find someone with the same issue :/

Here's what it looks like :

[image: Glitchy animation]

And here's what it's supposed to look like :

[image: Nice animation]

The paper on the left transform perfectly, but the shoe blinks.

Here's the code (Not mine but exactly the same, even this one doesn't work) : https://snack.expo.io/@chrfalch/shoe-shop

And it's from this guide : https://medium.com/@christian.falch/react-native-animation-challenge-1-7022e48a226

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally fixed it with `Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/air-jordan-1.png')).downloadAsync();`
Now it's looking beautiful :)